# How can I make a table for operations?

Tags: mysql, sql

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0eX5.jpg)

I attached the image of the ER diagram and here's the SQL code that I came up with. The problem is I don't know if it's right and I don't know how to implement the operations table.

```
CREATE TABLE catagory(
catagoryId INT,
Name VARCHAR(20),
Brakes VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(catagoryId)
);

CREATE TABLE AutoParts(
PartId INT,
PartName VARCHAR(20),
Description VARCHAR(20),
Price FLOAT(10),
PRIMARY KEY(PartId)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(
Id INT,
Name VARCHAR(20),
Address VARCHAR(50),
Phone INT,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee(
Id INT,
Name VARCHAR(20),
Email VARCHAR(20),
Phone INT,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE sub-catagory(
Name VARCHAR(20),
Type VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY EKY(Type)
);
```

Comment: draw.io has a diagramming tool

Comment: I do use it, but I need to know if the coding is right